# fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I installed FullCalendar 5 in my Angular 9 project

then I get this error in the console of browser and anything appears in the page

```
vdom.js:3 Uncaught Error: Please import the top-level full calendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.
    at Module../node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/vdom.js (vdom.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main.js (main.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js (main.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/demo/demo.component.ts (demo.component.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/Modules/app-routing.module.ts (app-routing.module.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular'; // for FullCalendar!
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FullCalendarModule // for FullCalendar!
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  calendarOptions = {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  };

}
```

```html
<full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

Comment: Any progress on this one? I'm also encountering this on FullCalendar v5 beta with Angular 7.2.15

Comment: if you are using Angular 7 then try FullCallendar V4

Answer (score 20):

For fixing this issue you need to import calendar core library at the top, then you need to initialize core lib in your constructor like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'; // include this line
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  calendarOptions = {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  };

 constructor() { 
    const name = Calendar.name; // add this line in your constructor
  }
}
```

Comment: `const name = Calendar.name;` is very important, as it prevents webpack from removing the referenced import during compilation

Comment: Gotta watch out for VS Code "source.organizeImports" or "source.sortImports", especially when triggered on editor save. Was executing a sizable find/replace across the codebase which inadvertently caused this error as the import required– _unavoidable pun_ –to be on top got sorted down.

Answer (score 3):

For those using Vue 3 + Vite, you have to import this:

```
import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom'
```

Source: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to deal with this:

Register your plugins in app.modules.ts:

```
import resourceTimeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap';

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([ // register FullCalendar plugins
   dayGridPlugin,
   interactionPlugin,
   bootstrapPlugin
]);

...
```

But in calenderOptions, you have to remove plugin property:

```
calendarOptions = {
-  plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrapPlugin],
   initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and fixed it by changing the order of the import libraries. What I did was `FullCalendarModule` library imported before the component in the `module.ts` like this below:

```
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular'; 
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'; 
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
    
import { MycalendarComponent } from './mycalendar/mycalendar.component';
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using **svelte** + **svelte-fullcalendar** + **vite@4.0.0**, here is the solution

Just import @fullcalendar/core/vdom before you import svelte-fullcalendar and other fullcalendar plugins. Like this:

```
import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom';
import FullCalendar from 'svelte-fullcalendar';
import daygridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
```

I am using this version (^2.0.0-beta.0) of svelte-fullcalendar along with **vite-4.0.1**