# Fullcalendar not working after replacing mix with vite in Laravel

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar, vite

I removed mix and and added vite to my Laravel 9 project. The only issue I'm facing is that [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) is no longer working.

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import { Calendar } from "@fullcalendar/core";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import listPlugin from "@fullcalendar/list";
import interaction from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import rrulePlugin from "@fullcalendar/rrule";
import deLocale from "@fullcalendar/core/locales/de";

window.Calendar = Calendar;
window.dayGridPlugin = dayGridPlugin;
window.timeGridPlugin = timeGridPlugin;
window.listPlugin = listPlugin;
window.deLocale = deLocale;
window.interaction = interaction;
```

**resources/views/test.blade.php**

```php
<div id='calendar'></div>

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function() {

            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {

                plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, rrulePlugin, interaction],

                initialView: "timeGridWeek",
                locale: deLocale,

                events: [],
            });

            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined
```

All my npm and composer dependencies are latest.

Comment: One of the first hits on google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239183/fullcalendar-lib-before-attempting-to-import-a-plugin

Comment: I read that and as you can see, the recommended solution is already in my code

Comment: Older question, but I'm also in the process of trying to use Fullcalendar in a `Vite` Laravel project (was previously Webpacker), had to add this line before `import { Calendar } ...`: `import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom'` (from the 3rd answer on the link from UnderDog). Everything else then seems to work (so far)